# Как настроить пользователя что бы приложение могло подключастья и работать с MS Sql базой данных?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Хочу подключиться к БД используя строку вида:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

Но не могу понять как настроить и где добавить нужного пользователя, везде уже подобавлял дал все права а все ровно происходит ошибка :

```
 System.Exception: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process.
```

Comment: Предположу что это может быть связано с политикой паролей, попробуйте зайти под этим пользователем через SSMS, так вы получите больше информации.

Comment: Решил проблему, Сервер->ПКМ->Свойства->Безопасность -> разрешить проверку подлинности SQL SERVER и WINDOWS, а перед этим на всякий случай В настройках SQL Server в пункте Сетевых соединение включил службу Named Pipes, хотя наверное это излишне

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Решил использовать встроенную запись sa и включил пользователя sa 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2) Сервер->ПКМ->Свойства->Безопасность -> разрешить проверку подлинности SQL SERVER и WINDOWS
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3) На всякий случай в настройках SQL Server в пункте Сетевых соединение включил службу Named Pipes, хотя наверное это излишне
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]